# SSH private keys fails when trying to login

Tags: ssh

I have a problem with SSH that keeps asking me for passphrase and password.

I first generated a public/private key-pair using:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C my-login@my-server.com
```

it ask me for a file to save the keys and a passphrase then generated:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C my-login@my-server.com
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/<USERNAME>/.ssh/id_rsa): SSH_priv_key
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in SSH_priv_key.
Your public key has been saved in SSH_priv_key.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:?? my-login@my-server.com

The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
.....
```

I then logged in to another shell and downloaded the private key from the first shell and entered:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/private-key.txt my-login@my-server.com
```

At first it asked for for the passphrase and the password. I did so (telling myself that this is maybe normal since its the first login from/to those shells).

Then I logged out and tried to login again but it keep asking me for passphrase and the password.

So I've read `man ssh-keygen`, googled read docs/tutorials and changed then entered command to:

```
$ ssh-keygen -trsa -b 2048 -f ~/.ssh/my-server.com
```

And tried to login again but got the same results.

I don't know what to do now?

Comment: "downloaded the private key" ... are you sure you're copying the right thing? Usually you copy your public key around, and keep your private key in the original system.

Comment: It's hard to tell how much you have obfuscated the `ssh-keygen` interaction, but if you *really* entered `SSH_priv_key` as the file name, then you will need to use `ssh -i SSH_priv_key my-login@my-server.com`

Comment: Be careful when manually coping ssh keys, `sshd` does only allow `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` with file permissions of user as owner and 0600. Typically umask is not setup this way.

Comment: Please clarify (in your question) on which of each of the two machines you're running each step. You shouldn't be generating a private key on a server that's then used from a client, for example.

Comment: Did you copy your public key to the target server? Use `ssh-copy-id user@server` for this task.

Comment: checking ~/.ssh/authorized_keys I realised that it was ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.temp as I renamed
to keep a backup while doing other operations and forgot to rename it back.

this is my mistake, sorry for that and tank's for your help